# Use double colons (::) in #define

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

May I use double colons in `#define` ? I'd like to save some writing in the implementation files, e.g. like this:

```
// foo.h
#define template template <class T>
#define foo:: foo<T>::

template class foo {
  T& baz();
};

#include "foo.tpp"
#undef template
#undef foo::

// foo.tpp
template T& foo::baz() {
    // do stuff.
}
```

But I get syntax errors I don't really understand.
(See an example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/yyu5UIzs) ):

> Line 11: error: missing whitespace after the macro name
>   Line 10: error: extra tokens at end of #undef directive
>   Line 4: error: 'foo' is not a template
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: Well asked question, but I'd post the syntax errors you get too

Comment: That looks like a truly bad idea to me, even if it worked (which thank God it doesn't). Nobody would be able to understand or maintain your code. Your successors would stick pins in your likeness.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  The name of a macro must be an identifier; it can't consist of other characters and it can't consist of multiple tokens.

`#define template` is invalid because `template` is not an identifier, it is a keyword.

`#define foo:: foo<T>::` was valid in C90 and C++98:  it defines a macro named `foo` that is replaced by `:: foo<T>::` (that's not what you want to do, but it was *valid*).  However, this is invalid in C99 and C++11 because in the newer revisions of the languages, there must be whitespace between the name of an object-like macro and its replacement list (the tokens with which it is replaced).