# How to replace class name and function name connected by double colon with #define preprocessor

Tags: c++

I have the code example

```
class test{

  void report(){
     global_class::report(arg1,arg2)
  }
}
```

Since the `global_class` has dependency on library I used, I want to do something like

```
#ifdef COMMON_C_
#define global_object::report(arg1.arg2) \ 
  do { std::cout<<arg1<<arg2<<endl;} while (0)
#endif

class test{

  void report(){
     global_object::report(arg1,arg2)
  }
}
```

Now it is just the standard outputs. But preprocess doesn't support the double colon I see. So `#define global_object::report(arg1.arg2)` is not allowed.

And I don't want to touch the void `report()` function at all. I mean if I can, I can define a macro for `global_object::report(arg1,arg2)`, use that macro inside `report()` and replace the macro under `ifdef`

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can do it the other way around, defining some symbol to either `global_object::report` or the other function. The preprocessor is very limited in its capabilities, by design.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863467/use-double-colons-in-define

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean but double colon ? PS: you get a . between your arg1 and arg2 in your macro it could be are : arg1, arg2 not arg1.arg2 :)

Comment: How about you state exactly what you want to do. "Macro magic" is naughty and should not be abused. Not to mention the syntactical errors in your code. And anyway consider @Miki's comment.

Comment: Why won't you just use different definitions for `global_object::report()` function? That is, create a different `global_object` class that will do what you want and just use that class?